# Raspberry Pi probably burned, but how?

Tags: raspbian, boot, boot-issues

I bought a new Pi 3. I was trying to make a LFR (line following robot). When I powered l239D IC with 14 volts, the Pi suddenly got off and restarted. It gave me the temperature of about 124 degrees celsius after restarting. Then it went off again and never got on again. My OS is Raspbian. Can you tell me where would have I possibly gone wrong?

Comment: You connected 14 volts to the Pi somehow.  Could you add a photo or schematic of the connections you made, preferably a photo.

Comment: L239D has two power supply pins, One that connect to pin 8 of the chip is for H-bridge driver and motor, and can be in the range of 4.5 - 36v. The one at pin 16 is 5V for internal logic and can be from the same power source of RPi. You probably wired the power supply wrongly and accidentally power the RPi with 14v.

Comment: @hcheung can you explain how could have I possibly powered my PI with 14 V other than with the USB cable it is already getting its power from?

Answer (score 1):

You mean I2**93**D, right? Sounds like a mismatch in power-supply. I agree with the guys in the comments, you are probably connecting a too high voltage to the Pi.

1. According to [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf) datasheet, you should work with pin 16
   instead of pin 8. [image]
2. I can also recommend you to connect the GND from the IC to the GND
   of the Pi, when you have more than one power supply. But I don't know if that's the case with you.

Comment: I gave 14 v to pin 8 of IC while gave 5 V from RPI pin board pin 2 to IC pin 16

Comment: Ignore "I connected 14" in the first comment.

Comment: So you want to supply the RPi with 5V from IC board pin 16, correct?

Comment: Re your point 2, the chip and Pi have to have a shared ground, otherwise the chip can not be controlled by the Pi.

Comment: No. The pi is already powered by usb cable. In order to power the IC, i am giving 5V from 2 pin of Rpi to pin 16 of IC. While giving my 14 volts  from battery to pin 8.

Comment: alright, in that case you really need to connect the GND's. Keep in mind that voltage is a difference between two points. 5V can be a total different value on the IC. When the ground of the Pi is connected with the ground of the IC you have the same reference in both devices. Hope this helps.